# Basic .emacs file for testing

Tags: emacs

I want to use a very basic `.emacs` file, as I am having a problem  with my current one. What would be a minimal contents in this file? I am trying to use gdb, however I cannot see the line skipping and I think it is related to the color scheme I am using.

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but is perhaps easier than trying to guess everything you may need in your setup to successfully run `gdb` (and nothing else besides that).  How about disabling the color scheme, or changing the color of that particular section that is not particularly visible -- place the cursor at that point in the buffer where the font color is not as you desire and type `M-x customize-face`.

Comment: I have tried setting a different `color-theme-` but has not resolved the problem. I have another computer and installed emacs and gdb. I can see gdb skipping the lines of code with easy viewable line highlight.

Comment: That file can be empty or missing and Emacs will still work... I'm not sure that you have sufficiently explained your needs.

Comment: I renamed it so emacs would not pick it up, however I am still stuck with the same problem. When one does `next line` in emacs, one should see the line being executed moving to the breakpoint. However I am not able so see that. The output is being changed, however I am not seeing the current location on the `.f` file.

Comment: @Zeus, it is hard to understand what you mean. Could you upload a screenshot and show what you want visually?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possibilities (independent):

1. You can use Emacs without any init file, by starting it using `emacs -Q` (or `runemacs -Q`).
2. You can just comment-out all or most or half or some of your init file.  Comment-out less and less until you remove only what was causing the problem.

To comment-out parts of the file, select the lines/text to comment out, and then use `M-x comment-region RET`.

To uncomment parts that you commented out, select them and then do `C-u M-x comment-region RET`. (The same command, but with a prefix argument.)

For convenience, I bind command `comment-region` to `C-x C-;`:

```
(define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?\;)] 'comment-region)
```

To quickly find out what part(s) of your init file are causing a problem, recursively bisect it: Comment out 1/2 of it (e.g. the first half).  Then, depending on which half is problematic, uncomment 1/4, then 1/8, etc., until you have commented out only the small part that is problematic.